# Chartjs - Stacked bar chart blocking other values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My problem is that chart js is rendering the bar chart based on the order defined on the dataset. As you can see below, the values at index 0 of the arrays are `2500` and `1000`. Since the 2500 was passed first, this will block the bar chart of the 1000 value.

https://jsfiddle.net/6bjy9nxh/352/

```
var barData = {
labels: ['Italy', 'UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan'],
datasets: [
    {
        label: '2010 customers #',
        fillColor: '#382765',
        data: [2500, 1902, 1041, 610, 1245, 952]
    },
    {
        label: '2014 customers #',
        fillColor: '#7BC225',
        data: [1000, 1689, 1318, 589, 1199, 1436]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per the example of Chartjs for Stacked bar chart `stacked: true` for both `xAxes` and `Axes`

```
var barData = {
    labels : ['Italy', 'UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan'],
    datasets : [{
        label : '2010 customers #',
        backgroundColor : '#382765',
        data : [2500, 1902, 1041, 610, 1245, 952]
    }, {
        label : '2014 customers #',
        backgroundColor : '#7BC225',
        data : [1000, 1689, 1318, 589, 1199, 1436]
    }]
};

var context = document.getElementById('clients').getContext('2d');
var clientsChart = new Chart(context, {
    type : 'bar',
    data : barData,
    options : {
        scales : {
            xAxes : [{
                stacked : true,

            }],
            yAxes : [{
                stacked : true
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

This may help you. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4e3k252/)

Comment: Your fiddle is showing the green bar at 3500 like it added the 1000 to the 2500. I'm expecting it to be at 1000. The green bar should be less than the blue bar

Comment: Ignore my comment. You are right. This is the correct answer