# Chartjs - Stacked bar chart data order causes invisible other values

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

Ive seen this thread:
[Chartjs - Stacked bar chart blocking other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535964/chartjs-stacked-bar-chart-blocking-other-values)

But still its not what im looking for. As author of previous thread pointed

> My problem is that chart js is rendering the bar chart based on the order defined on the dataset. As you can see below, the values at index 0 of the arrays are 2500 and 1000. Since the 2500 was passed first, this will block the bar chart of the 1000 value.
> https://jsfiddle.net/6bjy9nxh/352/

```
labels: ['Italy', 'UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan'],
datasets: [
    {
        label: '2010 customers #',
        fillColor: '#382765',
        data: [2500, 1902, 1041, 610, 1245, 952]
    },
    {
        label: '2014 customers #',
        fillColor: '#7BC225',
        data: [1000, 1689, 1318, 589, 1199, 1436]
    }
]
```

As my data is dynamic i dont know what value is higher thus i cant make order static.

Current behaviour if bigger data is passed as first:
[Current behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk0tc.png)

Expected behaviour:

[Expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fhpk.png)

Why im not accepting answer from previous thread? Because it sums values on Y axis:
[answer from other thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95zk7.png)

Comment: you can define rendering `order` per dataset so that small values get rendered on top bigger ones. but you cant define rendering order per data point.

Comment: yes so it wont solve my problem as its not said that first datasets is the biggest one for each X axis value

Answer (score -1):

Perhap you could give each of your dynamic datapoints an index, and then use css `z-index` to change the order of each individual index?

It seems like you can add [custom properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/data-structures/#object-using-custom-properties) to data in ChartJS. (I've not used it before but I've done something similar using Chartist)